# Can't push my local file into heroku with git push

Tags: git, heroku

Hello I logged in heroku and I want to push my own created server not their demo, I typed **cd c:\server** and then **git push heroku maste**r but I get this error: **Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git**
I tried push demo heroku and everything worked fine maybe problem in json files?

package.json

```
{
  "name": "server",
  "version": "0.2.6",
  "description": "A sample Node.js app using Express 4",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.2"
  },
  "main": "server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node server.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "ejs": "2.5.6",
    "express": "4.15.2"
  },
  "keywords": [
    "node",
    "heroku",
    "express"
  ],
  "license": "MIT"
}
```

Profile

```
web: node server.js
```

app.json

```
{
  "name": "Start on Heroku: Node.js",
  "description": "A barebones Node.js app using Express 4",
  "repository": "https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started",
  "logo": "https://cdn.rawgit.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started/master/public/node.svg",
  "keywords": ["node", "express", "heroku"],
  "image": "heroku/nodejs"
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Did you clone the repository first ? And from that same Repo directory are you pushing the files ?

Comment: I clone repository then took those json files and remake it to run my own created server.js, maybe i get this error because in json repository located in node-js-getting-started or it doesn't matter that my files different from those in git

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your current directory is not a git repository. Navigate to your directory and run the following commands:

```
git init
heroku git:remote -a your_app_name
```

Now you can change your files, commit them and push them using

```
git push
```

Comment: i got error when typed first code   Command failed: git remote
  fatal: Not a git repository (or any of the parent directories): .git

Comment: and then how to git push folder i want? go again cd to my directory? and type git push heroku master @31piy

Comment: @Tioww -- You need to learn about [basics of git](https://learnxinyminutes.com/docs/git/).

Comment: I did everything myself now seems all works good and heroku local works too but how to connect to web hosted server now because code like this not working var socket = io.connect('https://example-server.herokuapp.com:8080');

Comment: @Tioww -- Congratulations! Please raise a new question for your new problem, and accept the correct answer on this question.

Answer (score 1):

What you have to do is use the same folder where you have cloned the repo in, add / remove files as needed and push from there . 
As you have copied only the package.json to another file , git folder and information has not been copied . Hence git does not know what is the repo to push the code to .

So , just use the same folder , It should work fine then .

If you want to use it from somewhere else then copy all the contents to the desired folder then push.